# C++ template and std::any how to execute any generic function with generic parameters of different length and type

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++20, any

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
#include <any>
using namespace std;

int func1(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
int func1Wrapper(map<string, std::any> params)
{
    int a = any_cast<int>(params["a"]), b = any_cast<int>(params["b"]), c = any_cast<int>(params["c"]);
    return func1(a,b,c);
}

double func2(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
double func2Wrapper(map<string, std::any> params)
{
    int a = any_cast<int>(params["a"]), b = any_cast<int>(params["b"]);
    return func2(a,b);
}

int func3(int a, string b) {
    return a + b.length();
}
int func3Wrapper(map<string, std::any> params) 
{
    int a = any_cast<int>(params["a"]);
    string b = any_cast<string>(params["b"]);
    return func3(a,b);
}   

int func4(int a, vector<int> b) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (const auto& x : b) sum += x;
    return a + sum;
}
int func4Wrapper(map<string, std::any> params)
{
    int a = any_cast<int>(params["a"]);
    auto b = any_cast<vector<int>>(params["b"]);
    return func4(a,b);
}

typedef map<string, vector<map<string, any>>> FeatureMap;

vector<vector<std::any>> executor(map<string, vector<map<string, any>>> featureMap) 
{
    vector<vector<std::any>> res;
    for (auto it=featureMap.begin(); it!=featureMap.end(); it++)
    {
        vector<std::any> currentRes;
        if (it->first=="func1") {
            for (auto paramIt=it->second.begin(); paramIt!=it->second.end(); paramIt++)
                currentRes.push_back(func1Wrapper(*paramIt));
        }
        if (it->first=="func2") {
            for (auto paramIt=it->second.begin(); paramIt!=it->second.end(); paramIt++)
                currentRes.push_back(func2Wrapper(*paramIt));
        }
        if (it->first=="func3") {
            for (auto paramIt=it->second.begin(); paramIt!=it->second.end(); paramIt++)
                currentRes.push_back(func3Wrapper(*paramIt));
        }
        if (it->first=="func4") {
            for (auto paramIt=it->second.begin(); paramIt!=it->second.end(); paramIt++)
                currentRes.push_back(func4Wrapper(*paramIt));
        }

        res.push_back(currentRes);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    FeatureMap fm;
    fm["func1"] = { {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}} , {{"a", 3}, {"b", -4}, {"c", 5}} };
    fm["func2"] = { {{"a", 2}, {"b", 2}} , {{"a", 3}, {"b", -4}} };
    fm["func3"] = { {{"a", 3}, {"b", "hello"s}} , {{"a", 3}, {"b", "123"s}} };
    fm["func4"] = { {{"a", 4}, {"b", vector<int>({1,2,3})}}, {{"a", 3}, {"b", vector<int>({3,4,5})}} };
    
    auto res = executor(fm);
    auto func1Res = res[0], func2Res = res[1], func3Res = res[2], func4Res = res[3];

    cout << any_cast<int>(func1Res[0]) << " " << any_cast<int>(func1Res[1]) << "\n";
    cout << any_cast<double>(func2Res[0]) << " " << any_cast<double>(func2Res[1]) << "\n";
    cout << any_cast<int>(func3Res[0]) << " " << any_cast<int>(func3Res[1]) << "\n";
    cout << any_cast<int>(func4Res[0]) << " " << any_cast<int>(func4Res[1]) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am converting a Python library to C++, it uses `dict()` everywhere.
A 1-1 conversion is like the code above: an executor accept a list of function, each function can have different parameter types and length. I store the parameters in a `map<string, std::any> params`, and for each function I have to manually extract the parameter then manually call the function (like `func1Wrapper`).

This code is very tedious to use and update. More importantly, it's very slow since there are `map and std::any` everywhere. I wish to use template to do as much thing as possible at compile time.

Is there anyway to convert the above code to using template? The executor should be able to accept any function with any parameter (different length, different types, ...). Instead of using a `map<string, std::any> params`, a user must give the function parameters in the correct order.

**Edit:** if the above is impossible, then what should I use to achieve similar functionality? Basically, the executor should be able to perform:

```
vector<vector<std::any>> res;
vector<vector<vector<std::any>> param_list;
for (i=0; i<function_list.size(); i++):
{
    vector<std::any> currentRes;
    for (j=0; j<param_list[i].size(); j++)
        currentRes.push_back(function_list[i](param_list[i][j]));
    res.push_back(currentRes);
}
```

while using as much compile-time stuffs as possible.

Comment: Do you have to be able to call the functions by string name? Or is using a symbol acceptable? I.e. using `foo` instead of `"foo"`? Also, do you have to support runtime maps, or would a compile time list of functions suffice?

Comment: C++ is a strongly typed language. Python is not. This is what happens when you try to use idioms from one language in a language that doesn't support those idioms.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR compile time list of function is enough. So for example I will push function pointer foo instead of string "foo"

Comment: @NicolBolas so how can I make the above program faster? I know that the solution is template, but I don't know how

Comment: Your executor seems to accept a collection of essentially *deferred function calls* and execute them in order. In C++, a deferred function call can be expressed as a function object (a lambda, a result of `std::bind`, or a custom written callable object).

Comment: @HuyLe: Step 1 would be to maybe not pass *everything* by value like that. Step 2 would be to stop *trying* to treat C++ like it's not a strongly typed language and start treating it like it's C++. As in, stop trying to make functions that can accept anything without a good reason for that, and don't try to make dynamic dispatch work that way. Basically, learn C++ idioms, not how to make this code go faster.

Comment: @NicolBolas i'm aware that everything should be const&, I'm just simplifying the question. "As in, stop trying to make functions that can accept anything without a good reason for that" then what should I do to achieve the same functionality like in the example?

Answer (score 2):

> The executor should be able to accept any function with any parameter (different length, different types, ...).

You can use a combination of **perfect forwarding** and **variadic templates** as shown below. In the program shown, the function template `forwardToArbitFunc<>` accepts any number of function call arguments and forwards each of them to another function(which is also passed as the first argument to the function template).

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

//this function template forwards its arguments to arbitrary function 
template<typename T, typename... Ts> void forwardToArbitFunc(T g,Ts&&... xs)
{
     g(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...); // forward all xs to g()
}

void func()
{
    std::cout<<"parameterless func called"<<std::endl;
}
void func2(int a)
{
    std::cout<<"one parameter func2 called"<<std::endl;
}
void func3(std::string a, int b)
{
    std::cout<<"two parameter func3 called"<<std::endl;
}
void func4(std::string a, std::string b, float c, double d)
{
    std::cout<<"four parameter func4 called"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    forwardToArbitFunc(func);
    
    forwardToArbitFunc(func2, 3);
    
    forwardToArbitFunc(func3, "some string", 5);
    
    forwardToArbitFunc(func4, "some string", "another string", 4.4, 5.5);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/1F-Tt_wgR)

Comment: It isn't clear why `forwardToArbitFunc` is needed. Why not just write `func4("some string", "another string", 4.4, 5.5)` instead?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Because in the question OP said that *"executor should be able to accept any function with any parameter (different length, different types, ...). Instead of using a map<string, std::any> params, a user must give the function parameters in the correct order."* Ofcourse, we can also directly call `func`, `func2` etc. But OP seems to be already aware of that. And asking about how to accept a function with any parameter.

Comment: `forwardToArbitFunc` is a no-op. OP's executor either does the same thing as `forwardToArbitFunc`, in which case it is a no-op too and can be eliminated altogether, or does something else, in which case `forwardToArbitFunc` doesn't help.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. My only aim was to show OP how to make use of template which he/she asked for.

Comment: @AnoopRana can you modify the function so that it accepts a **vector** of param instead of just a single param? Basically, I wish forwardToArbitFunc to specify a function once and execute a list of param. So it should return vector<std::any>, not just void

Comment: @HuyLe If you want to specify the function only once(as mentioned in you last comment), then how you intend to call different functions with different parameters? Can you clarify some more here. I mean say you specify `func` once, then how will you call `func2`, `func3` etc since we've not specified them.

Comment: @AnoopRana I mean each different function is specified once. For example, `fm["func3"] = { {{"a", 3}, {"b", "hello"s}} , {{"a", 3}, {"b", "123"s}} };` means calculate func3(3, "hello") and func3(3,"123"). I want to do that instead of writing func3(3,"hello") and func3(3,"123") separately